# VS2015 WPF Debugging Black Toolbar

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I've noticed some toolbar is appearing when I debug WPF applications from VS2015, but I have no idea what it is.  It is annoying.

[image: toolbar]

What is it?

Can I disable it?

Comment: I'd also like to point out, that this thing can cause UI problems when debugging.  I was using a WPF `Popup` control and having this feature enabled caused it to disappear instantly upon opening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's XAML debugging tools. The controls are under the Tools - Options menu.

[image: UI Debugging Tools for XAML]

Related:

- [Introducing the UI debugging tools for XAML](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/02/24/introducing-the-ui-debugging-tools-for-xaml/)
- [General, Debugging, Options Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85yzd16c.aspx)